# PHP urlencode functions

Tags: php, html, mysql, url, encode

I am having trouble making the 'url' column based on 'topicnaam' with the function `urlencode`

**What I want:** I want my url made by the topicnaam. But the topicnaam needs an urlencode so their are no spaces and other symbols in the 'url'

[I tried to use the `urlencode()` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php).

[This is my table structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WG1pv.png)

my code for the `<form>` and the update functions

```
<?php
  if(isset($_POST['react_btn'])){
   unset($q1);
   $q1['topicnaam'] = $app->check_string($_POST['topicnaam']);
   $q1['board_id'] = $app->check_string($_POST['boardid']);
   $q1['klant_id'] = $app->check_string($_POST['klantid']);
   $q1['ledenpagina_id'] = $app->check_string($_POST['ledenpaginaid']);
   $q1['omschrijving'] = $app->check_string($_POST['topicomschrijving']);
   $app->insert_query('topics', $q1, 'id');
   }  

  ?> 
   <form action="" method="post">
     <div class="form-group">
      <label for="comment">Topicnaam:</label>
      <textarea class="form-control resizenone" name="topicnaam" rows="1" id="comment" required></textarea>
       <input type="hidden" name="klantid" value="<?php echo $_SESSION["klant_id"] ?>">
       <input type="hidden" name="boardid" value="<?php echo $actiefboardid ?>">
       <input type="hidden" name="ledenpaginaid" value="<?php echo $_SESSION["ledenpagina_id"]; ?>">
       <label for="comment">Topic omschrijving:</label>
       <textarea class="form-control resizenone" name="topicomschrijving" rows="3" id="comment required"></textarea>
       <button type="submit" name="react_btn" class="btn btn-primary">Voeg topic toe</button>
       </div>              
   </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find it here

```
if(isset($_POST['react_btn'])){
    $base_URL = 'https://yousitename.com/'

    unset($q1);
    $q1['topicnaam'] = $app->check_string($_POST['topicnaam']);
    $q1['board_id'] = $app->check_string($_POST['boardid']);
    $q1['klant_id'] = $app->check_string($_POST['klantid']);
    $q1['ledenpagina_id'] = $app->check_string($_POST['ledenpaginaid']);
    $q1['omschrijving'] = $app->check_string($_POST['topicomschrijving']);
    $q1['url'] = $base_URL.urlencode($q1['topicnaam']);
    $app->insert_query('topics', $q1, 'id');
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this mate! it worked. I had to adjust the code a little bit but I got it working.